# Why can we not graph a $4D $linear equation?

Tags: soft-question, education

My names is Shaun and I am $13$ years old.

I find this an important question to ask, because we can solve a system of **four variables**, but we *think* we cannot ***graph it***. Yes, I agree, as humans who sadly cannot visualize $4D$, we would not be able to answer this question in depth. However, we know it is possible to graph it, as all the lines intersect at a specific point.

And if we can visualize it (as I have researched on many websites, like Wikipedia, Quora, Stack Exchange and so forth), then how can we visualize it? Through lines, or shapes$?$ Colours maybe$?$

When I say we can solve a system of four variables, I mean that we solve equations like this:

$w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2 = 8 $

$x^2w^2 + z^2y^2 = 4 $

Does anyone, who is experienced enough, know how to answer this question$?$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> A number of rhetorical elements in the question read like inoculations against being told the question cannot be answered; could you please edit to focus on what is being asked? For example, "How can we visualize the solution set of the system $w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $wz - xy=0$ [or whatever] in four variables?" (Context suggests the intended emphasis is on four or more _variables_, rather than on four _equations_.)

Comment: Thank you, @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: When dealing with complex functions it is common to either: draw two Cartesian planes side-by-side, for the input/output; draw a single plane but colour code it with “domain colouring”; draw a single plane but identify certain contour lines that correspond to the images of certain other lines (the choice being up to the grapher).